# Insert path in file

Tags: files, path

Given a file, `/opt/file.dat`, how do I insert the path to the file (`/opt`) as the first line of `file.dat`?

Comment: As the first line of what? Can you give examples?

Comment: Hi, I have a text file called file.dat and located D\CC3\cc3_15_1. I would like to insert a line within file.dat which tells its path (D\CC3\cc3_15_1) as first line of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find some nifty one liners and make aliases out of them, but typically once you have a handful of commands a script is better because it is more flexible, hopefully more readable, and you can expand its functionality later a lot easier once you say "Oh! I should also make it do *x*...". So, here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add filepath to first line of file

myFile="file.dat"
filePath=`pwd`
tmpFile="tmpFile"

cp $myFile $tmpFile
echo $filePath | cat - $tmpFile > $myFile
rm $tmpFile

exit 0
```

Don't forget to make it executable: `chmod u+x addPath.sh` (assumes you saved the above script to a file `addPath.sh`).

Comment: For example, one useful way to expand this script is to add a bash `for` loop to get not only "file.dat" but all files in the working directory, or all files matching a pattern (say, `*.c`).

Comment: Hi, Thank you it worked. As you suggested I try to make a loop to add as first line in each file contained in the working directory, the path of these files. I keep your script and add before the command: 

    <For $$myFile IN (.) DO (
    cp $myFile $tmpFile
    echo $filePath | cat - $tmpFile > $myFile
    rm $tmpFile
    exit 0) >

But I get the error message "syntax error near unexpected token '(' " Any idea why ?

Comment: You would need to do something like `\`ls\`` instead of the `.` you have. There are a lot of examples available online for bash for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Just display the path of the file then the whole file and redirect in into the file

```
PATH_TO_FILE=/path/to/file

TMP_FILE=`mktemp`

echo $PATH_TO_FILE | cat - $PATH_TO_FILE > $TMP_FILE & cp $TMP_FILE $PATH_TO_FILE
```